# Внедрение JS-кода локально.

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
Как внедрить свой JS код в исходный код сайта автоматически. Стоит такая задача: нажать на кнопку на сайте.

Answer (score 2):

[Userjs](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userjs).

Comment: Полистаю....

Comment: Не только :-)

[Greasemonkey][1] работает в Лисе, [Опере][2], [Хроме][3], [Safari][4], [эксплорере][5]


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey
  [2]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userjs
  [3]: http://www.ghacks.net/2010/02/02/google-chrome-4-natively-supports-greasemonkey-scripts/
  [4]: http://8-p.info/greasekit/
  [5]: http://www.bhelpuri.net/Trixie/

Comment: @mantigatos, вот это действительно то, что мне нужно! Жаль, что это комментарий, а не ответ, а так бы заработали пару десятков очков =)

Comment: @Asen читать нужно внимательнее, по моей ссылке всё написано, что, и для чего нужно.

Comment: В принципе, как прочитал про UserJs И про Greasemonkey, оказало практически идентичным...

Answer (score 1):

```
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.innerHTML="alert('Hello, World!')";
document.head.appendChild(e);
```

В e.innerHTML пишешь свой скрипт. Не забывай экранировать двойные кавычки и ставить "+" или "\" в конце каждой строке
Пример:

```
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.innerHTML="alert(\"Hello, World!\") +
             alert('Goodbye, World') \
             // Комментарий "
document.head.appendChild(e);
```

Одинарные кавычки можно не экранировать.
Решение абсолютно кроссбраузерное